# why does my laptop windows 10 system font have strange whiteness behind letters on my LG high res HDMI monitor but not on laptop screen?

Tags: windows, windows-10, display, fonts, lg-monitor

The system fonts have a distracting "shine" to them.
When I looked closely, backgrouds of some letters are whiter.

I init'd ClearType, no effect.

Comment: Some screen shots would help us understand your question. Upload any image(s) to [Imgur](http://www.imgur.com) and you will get link(s) you can share. [Edit] your question to include the link(s) and someone with sufficient reputation will inline the image(s) for you.

Comment: Did you perhaps change the monitor's settings? Like "Sharpness"? Reset them.